# Python AIML Kernel Startup error

Tags: python, chatbot, aiml

I'm trying to run a script to create a chat-bot with AIML Python module, and I'm new to python, whenever I run the script to initialize the chat-bot, during the first phase of execution and compiling it shows an error importing Kernel module, as follows:

[image: module import error]

The Code Is As Below:

```
import aiml
# Create the kernel and learn AIML files
kernel = aiml.Kernel()
kernel.learn("std-startup.xml")
kernel.respond("load aiml b")

# Press CTRL-C to break this loop
while True:
    kernel.respond(raw_input("Enter your message >> "))
```

The file Structure for the aiml directory is:

[image: AIML Directory For Python]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the error it looks like - you are using python 3

the `aiml` package works only with python 2

you should either use python 2 or use a different aiml package for python 3

I guess there are quite a few of them - below is the one I  heard of

[Py3kAiml](https://github.com/huntersan9/Py3kAiml)

Answer (score 3):

Check your **init**.py file.

I added following code for **init**.py file which is in the aiml directory.

```
from .Kernel import Kernel
```